# Configure location of HTML element closing bracket in Prettier

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I use VS Code with Prettier in Angular project (`esbenp.prettier-vscode`)

Is it possible to configure where closing bracket will be located? For example, this is how Prettier formats HTML file:

```
<textarea
   class="textarea"
   type="text"
   contentEditable="true"
   placeholder="Placeholder"
></textarea>
```

Instead I would like it to format like this:

```
<textarea
   class="textarea"
   type="text"
   contentEditable="true"
   placeholder="Placeholder">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Use `"bracketSameLine": true` .
Reference: [Prettier 2.4](https://prettier.io/blog/2021/09/09/2.4.0.html)